# Should questions in SciFi Stack Exchange about the meaning/use of Adverbs/Prepositions in Harry Potter start being deleted?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've started noticing too many questions in SciFi Stack Exchange about the meaning of adverbs/prepositions, mainly in Harry Potter tag. With a simple search with [relevant tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), someone would always see 3-5 questions in recents (e.g., *"what does 'there' refer to"* etc.).

Although someone might argue that these are legit questions (I don't imply that these people are trolling, they honestly seek for advice to understand the meaning, most probably because English is not their first language), SciFi Stack Exchange is **not** there to answer to linguistic questions. There is [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Instead of having these questions there all the time, that usually receive a high number of downvotes, should the questions start being purged from the site?

Comment: We don’t delete questions because they’re off topic. This has also been asked before so bear with whilst I dig the question up.

Comment: Note: let me know if you think this warrants re-discussing and I’ll reopen the question. Note the linked questions on the dupe though; this has come up a lot per the years.

Comment: These questions represent a tiny proportion of the questions on the site. If you personally don't like them, have you tried ignoring them instead?

Comment: SFF SE used to have a "general reference" close reason, but this was done away with because the list of references couldn't be agreed on, essentially reduced to Wikipedia.  History SE kept it; it's called "too basic". If you want to go the "too basic" route, it'll be a hard slog. For now, just count on the downvotes to discurage these questions.  Or if you can think of a good enough rationale to get a mod to close it, flag it and leave a comment.

Comment: @Spencer It was more that one person's 'too basic' is another person's 'too difficult'. One setting might have a in-universe meaning that only experts in that tag understand. The whole thing is untenable.

Comment: If people want "What's the meaning of X" questions to be automatically deleted, then we need to stop answering them.

Comment: So far, they tend to basically be plot questions, with it being as reasonable to answer them as questions along the lines of "Who was the mysterious female in the background during the trial scene in *Magnificent Mim's Prosecutorial Puff Piece*?" (hypothetical work/question).

Comment: I'm a mod on History, and the "too basic" close reason works well there. It's basically equivalent to "answer can be found in a basic encyclopedia, textbook, or similar standard reference work". SFF doesn't have a standard set of reference works that could define what "too basic" means.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Yes. [This one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259471/who-exactly-is-her-here) seemed particularly egregious, and it's what brought me here to comment, but I thinks that's where the downvotes do their job.

Comment: @robertC my issue is that the close reason doesn't point the user at where to find good resources. If they don't have access to Wikipedia (or extended internet use) or a library this may be the only place they can ask.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - The key issue is always that "too basic" is far too subjective. The more of an expert you are in something, the more foolish and naive other people's questions look

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Why should we stop answering questions that are perfectly well on topic just because some users don't like them.

Comment: @Valorum  I said "If people want "What's the meaning of X" questions to be automatically deleted", what you are doing is providing a counter argument, i.e. you do not want them automatically deleted. I made no claim they were off-topic, just how the answers prevent automatic deletion.